# how to run crond and vsftpd on alpine linux docker container?

Tags: docker

I would like to run crond and vstfpd on a docker container.

First, I've created an alpine-vstfpd docker container:

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN apk update && apk add vsftpd
RUN adduser -h /home/./files -s /bin/false -D files
RUN echo "local_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo "chroot_local_user=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo "write_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo "local_umask=022" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo "passwd_chroot_enable=yes" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo 'seccomp_sandbox=NO' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo 'pasv_enable=Yes' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo 'pasv_max_port=10100' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && echo 'pasv_min_port=10090' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf \
  && sed -i "s/anonymous_enable=YES/anonymous_enable=NO/" /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
VOLUME /home/files
EXPOSE 20 21 10090-10100
```

Next I've created another container that uses the previous one:

```
FROM alpine-vsftpd
COPY myScript /bin/myScript
COPY root /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
RUN chmod +x /bin/myScript
CMD /usr/sbin/crond -f -l 2 -L /var/log/cron.log && /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

When the container is started, only runs crond. If switch the commands, only runs vsftpd:

```
CMD /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf && /usr/sbin/crond -f -l 2 -L /var/log/cron.log
```

Trying to use an intermediate script, occurs the same, only runs the first one:

```
FROM alpine-vsftpd
COPY myScript /bin/myScript
COPY root /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
RUN chmod +x /bin/myScript
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
CMD /entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 2 -L /var/log/cron.log
/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Now only runs crond. If the lines are switched, only runs vsftpd.

Why only run the first one?
How can run both?

Answer (score 1):

Run one task as background task and the other as main foreground task:

```
/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 2 -L /var/log/cron.log | /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Also (this might be fairly late, but in case it helps someone in future), I forgot to mention that [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) could be used for running multiple processes too.

Comment: I've put it on CMD and it works. Thank you very much. But, why doesn't work using entrypoint.sh?

Comment: Because once a foreground task starts, execution on that thread won't proceed until that task is ended. So you run one task in some background thread and another on main thread.

Also, there isn't really much difference on how commands execute in CMD vs entrypoint. So above applies to both CMD and entrypoint (try running each individual command in CMD; the result should make this obvious to you (you will have to end daemon manually by Ctrl+C)).

Comment: In this case both start, but vsftpd doesn't respond when try to connect to it. I need to put both in background to work: CMD /usr/sbin/crond -l 2 -L /var/log/cron.log | /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf